# Why does my Cassandra sometimes show operation timed out error?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have 130.000 data rows and I have many read, write and delete operations on cassandra.

Sometimes this error message occurs and this means there must be some error in my system but I don't know where and what is wrong:

```
code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' 
responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." 
info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE'}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Increase the `write_request_timeout_in_ms` in the Cassandra Config file (cassandra.yaml) to a bigger number. This error occurs when the reads are fast and your writes are taking longer(hence timing out).

Try something like :

```
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 20000
```

and restart your Server.